# What is the real purpose of Stemming in NLP?

Tags: nlp, stemming, lemmatization

I know about stemming and lemmatizing as follows:
stemming - converts words into non-changing portions;amusing, amusement - amus
lemmatizing - converts words to dictionary form ; amusing, amusement - amuse
I can understand why to use lemmatization. But I dont get the purpose behind doing stemming ? Can you explain ?

Comment: What do you understand with the output of stemming ? How do you interpret it ?

Answer (score 2):

As you said *stemming - converts words into non-changing portions*

and *lemmatizing - converts words to dictionary form*

Machine Learning algorithms like BOW or tf-idf are related to **word frequency**

Let's take an example you provided in your question.

with stemming

`amusing, amusement` both words returns `amus` so these words will be treated as same and frequency for `amus` will be 2.

with lemmatization
`amusing, amusement` both words returns `amuse` so again these words will be treated as same and frequency for `amuse` will be 2

In your model it doesn't matter(in this particular case) if you use either stemming or lemma

Stemming just stripping the letters from the word while lemmatization requires looking into dictionary to find related word so obviously is faster stemming than lemmatization

So you can choose `stemming` over `lemmatization` if you want to speed up preprocessing

**Disadvantage**

In case of stemming

studying will give study   and
studies will give studi

even those words have same root, these words will be treated as different